# L'Hospital's Rule for a function not a fraction

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

My answer was $\infty$ because at the end I got $\infty-\infty$ , yet I feel this is wrong?
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(xe^\frac{1}{x}-x)$$

Comment: This is $\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{e^y-1}y$.

Comment: $\infty-\infty$ isn't always $\infty$ it can be pretty much anything from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\infty-\infty$ is called [**an indeterminate form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). It is so called because it's not really clear what's going to with the limit as $x$ approaches a certain number or, as in your case here, infinity. For all intents and purposes, an indeterminate form can't be and never is the answer to a limit problem because it doesn't answer the question of whether the limit exists or not. When you get an indeterminate form, it means that you actually need to do some more work to find the limit. In your case, notice that $\frac{x}{1}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ as long as $x$ does not equal zero (it's not in our case here):

\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(xe^\frac{1}{x}-x\right)
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(e^\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^\frac{1}{x}-1}{\frac{1}{x}}\\
&=\frac{0}{0}\text{ is an indeterminate form, apply L'Hospital's rule}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(e^\frac{1}{x}-1\right)'}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)'}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{x^2}e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\frac{1}{x}}\\
&=e^{0}\\
&=1
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative note that

$$\left(x\left[\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\right]^\frac{1}{x}-x\right)=x+1-x=1
\leq (xe^\frac{1}{x}-x)1\leq$$
$$\leq \left(x\left[\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x+1}\right]^\frac{1}{x}-x\right)=\left(x+1\right)\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{\frac1x}-x\stackrel{\text{Bernoulli's inequality}}\leq$$
$$\leq(x+1)\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)-x=x+\frac1x+1+\frac1{x^2}-x=1+\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}\to1$$

thus for squeeze theorem

$$(xe^\frac{1}{x}-x)\to1$$

Comment: is there something wrong? Please do not hesitate to let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I think for $x\rightarrow+\infty$ it's just sandwich. +1

Comment: Thanks Michael, your check is the best validation I can look for! If you need a check for some inequality...no not ask to me :)

Comment: How did you get the last limit (the one which is bounding our function from above) as $1$? I don't think it is very obvious and in fact also of type $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That's a very good point! I need to revise. Thanks!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I've updated the solution!

Comment: Bernoulli is $\geq$ and not $\leq$ as you have written. The simplest approach here seems to use $1/x=t$ and it becomes one of standard limits.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Note that I've used the Bernoulli's inequality in the form $(1+x)^r\leq 1+rx$ for $0\leq r \leq1$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality.

Comment: Got it! BTW I had never used Bernoulli with exponent between $0$ and $1$. +1 already delivered.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Maybe I should specify and highlight this particular case of the inequality in the answer, It's really a good trick here to upper bound the function! Thanks again for your initial remarks which pointed out an important gap in the derivation.

Answer (score 1):

It's $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}{\frac{1}{x}}=1$$
because for example $$\left(e^x\right)'_{x=0}=e^0=1.$$

Comment: @Miichael Please could you take a look at my anser for any error? Thanks!